# Mac OS X - Store a single restore point in Dropbox

Tags: mac, backup, dropbox, time-machine

I just finished setting up a new MacBookPro with my standard setup (think like a boilerplate). Every year or two I like to wipe my machine and start fresh again. So before my system gets too cluttered I would like to create a restore point of this moment that I can come back to, or possibly even setup a new machine with.

I came across articles like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/435267/is-it-possible-use-dropbox-as-my-osx-time-machine-backup-drive) that makes it seem impossible, but I think the question is often considered as a backup solution which is not what I'm looking for. I simple want a one time only restore point that I can use to reset or setup a new machine.

Any thoughts, suggestions or answers would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to clone your drive in this "nice" state using [SuperDuper!](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [CarbonCopyCloner](https://bombich.com) and save this clone as a disk-image. This image can then be stored wherever you want and be used as something you restore the computer from later. It might be quite large though so I'm not sure that Dropbox is the best way to store it, but if it works for you it's great!

You can either clone the image (with the same software) to the drive you want to install OSX on or it might even be possible to use the OSX disk utility setup tools and make a "restore from ..." action with the image as source.